# Increase allocated nodes for queued jobs on a PBS cluster

Tags: batch-jobs

I have submitted a job on a PBS managed cluster using `qsub -l nodes=5:ppn=16`. My job is queued and is waiting for other jobs to be completed.

Is there a command that allows me change the number of allocated nodes for queued jobs?

I can simply delete the job using qdel and submit it again with more number of nodes. However, doing this would mean that I will lose my position in the queue (my job will go to the bottom of the queue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `qalter`, but it might be that there are restrictions on what you can change.

`qalter -f <jobID>` shows a list of resources available.

`qalter -l nodes=5:ppn=16` will be used to alter the nodes.

Comment: [link](http://www.upv.es/upl/U0115424.htm)
It seems like changing the resource should work. This [link](http://www.dcsc.sdu.dk/docs/doc/job_resource_management.php) gives an example of changing nodes  `code` qalter -l nodes=XX job-id. This doesnt works for me, I get an error saying unknown resource type.

Comment: Did you also try `qalter -l nodes=6:ppn=16 <jobid>`? It also might be that you only can lower the resources.

Comment: I get the same error by including ppn and also if I try to lower the resource. qalter -l mem_free=2G -l mem_token=2G  3185289. This is an example for increasing the memory but I dont know what is the right resource name for increasing nodes.

Comment: Check your resource list with `qstat -f <jobid>`. Maybe you can find a hint there. Otherwise I would recommend to contact the cluster admins.

Comment: qstat -f helped. I was making a typo, qalter -l nodes=6:ppn=16 is the right command but it didnt allowed me to increase the nodes as there was a limit set to the resource value. 
Thanks.